# How to make sure fragment is created before accessing adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm still trying to find the correct design for my application in order to prevent calls to an adapter for a listview in two separate fragments in a `tab host` of my application.

I have so far when accessing the adapter for the listviews, only been able to access the value while it is null, I'm assuming because the fragment isn't completely set up yet and the adapter hasn't been created yet, though I am not certain. How can I make sure that the adapter is set up before accessing it in a call to pubnub?

The only answers I have found have been to use a handler to delay the event until after the fragments are set up, but this doesn't work for me. The adapters are still null.

Fragment 1:

```
public class GroupChatFragment extends Fragment{

public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private Context context;

public GroupChatFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_chat, container, false);
    ListView chatListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chatList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    chatListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class GroupTasksFragment extends Fragment {

public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private Context context;

public GroupTasksFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_tasks, container, false);
    ListView taskListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tasksList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    taskListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

The class referencing the fragments (lines accessing the adapters have been commented out for clarity):

```
public class GroupContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GroupChatFragment chatFrag;
private GroupTasksFragment taskFrag;
private PubNub connection;
private String groupName;
private String nickName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_content);
    FragmentTabHost tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tasks").setIndicator("Tasks"),
            GroupTasksFragment.class, null);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("chat")
            .setIndicator("Chat"), GroupChatFragment.class, null);

    groupName = getIntent().getStringExtra("groupName");
    nickName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nickName");
    PNConfiguration config = new PNConfiguration();
    config.setPublishKey("pub-c-d8414fbe-6925-4511-9bda-8fa682138fb1");
    config.setSubscribeKey("sub-c-50acdc56-c1a3-11e6-b07a-0619f8945a4f");
    connection = new PubNub(config);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            chatFrag = (GroupChatFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("chat");
            taskFrag = (GroupTasksFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tasks");
            connection.history()
                    .channel(groupName)
                    .count(50)
                    .async(new PNCallback<PNHistoryResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(PNHistoryResult result, PNStatus status) {
                            for (PNHistoryItemResult item : result.getMessages()) {
                                String[] sForm = item.getEntry().getAsString().split(">>>>");
                                String m = "";
                                if (sForm.length > 2) {
                                    for (int x = 1; x < sForm.length; x++) {
                                        m += sForm[x];
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    m = sForm[1];
                                }

                                switch (sForm[0]) {
                                    case "chat":
                                        //chatFrag.adapter.add(m);
                                        break;
                                    case "addTask":
                                        if (taskFrag.adapter.getPosition(m) < 0) {
                                            //taskFrag.adapter.add(m);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "deleteTask":
                                        if (taskFrag.adapter.getPosition(m) >= 0) {
                                            //taskFrag.adapter.remove(m);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    case "groupCreated":
                                        //taskFrag.adapter.clear();
                                        //chatFrag.adapter.clear();
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            connection.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
                @Override
                public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
                    if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You were disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory) {
                        if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory) {
                            pubnub.publish().channel(groupName).message("chat>>>><ADMIN> User '" + nickName + "' Connected").async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNReconnectedCategory) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You were reconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {
                    String[] sForm = message.getMessage().getAsString().split(">>>>");
                    String m = "";
                    if (sForm.length > 2) {
                        for (int x = 1; x < sForm.length; x++) {
                            m += sForm[x];
                        }
                    } else {
                        m = sForm[1];
                    }

                    switch (sForm[0]) {
                        case "chat":
                            //chatFrag.adapter.add(m);
                            break;
                        case "addTask":
                            //taskFrag.adapter.add(m);
                            connection.publish().channel(groupName).message("chat>>>><ADMIN> Task '" + m + "' added.").async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(PNPublishResult pnPublishResult, PNStatus pnStatus) {
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                        case "deleteTask":
                            //taskFrag.adapter.remove(m);
                            connection.publish().channel(groupName).message("chat>>>><ADMIN> Task '" + m + "' deleted.").async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(PNPublishResult pnPublishResult, PNStatus pnStatus) {
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {
                }
            });
            connection.subscribe().channels(java.util.Collections.singletonList(groupName)).execute();
        }
    }, 100);
}

public void goHome(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void sendMessage(View v) {
    String message = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageToSend)).getText().toString();
    connection.publish().channel(groupName).message("chat>>>><" + nickName + "> " + message).async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(PNPublishResult pnPublishResult, PNStatus pnStatus) {
        }
    });
}

public void deleteTask(View v) {
    final EditText input = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    input.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Delete Task")
            .setMessage("What task would you like to delete?")
            .setView(input)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (taskFrag.adapter.getPosition(input.getText().toString()) < 0) {
                        connection.publish().channel(groupName).message("deleteTask>>>>" + input.getText().toString()).async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(PNPublishResult pnPublishResult, PNStatus pnStatus) {
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.cancel();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This task doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.CANCEL, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
}

public void addTask(View v) {
    final EditText input = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
    input.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Create New Task")
            .setView(input)
            .setMessage("What task would you like to create?")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (taskFrag.adapter.getPosition(input.getText().toString()) >= 0) {
                        connection.publish().channel(groupName).message("addTask>>>>" + input.getText().toString()).async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(PNPublishResult pnPublishResult, PNStatus pnStatus) {
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.cancel();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This task already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.CANCEL, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .show();
    }
}
```

I've also considered using static variables and such, but I can't see how I can use static variables as set up status and still use the code in a method because the methods and variables would have to be static, and the PubNub calls can't be.

I also can't make the variables public and do something like that because no instance can be passed to the fragments because of how they are set up.

Is there some way to do this with the fragment to activity communication interface sort of thing?

EDIT: Added code from first answer to fragments, still resulting in null adapters.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You are returning another view to your Fragment when you're using another to initialize your subviews:

   ```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_tasks, container, false);
   ```

   is the view you should be returning instead of:

   ```
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_chat, container, false);
   ```

   Just do this:

   ```
   return rootView;
   ```
2. You're not utilising the `onAttach()` method you have overridden in your    Fragment class. Do this:

   ```
   private Context context;
   ```

   and in your `onAttach` method,

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);
      this.context = context; //when fragment is created, context will be initialised.
   }
   ```

   Now, with your adapter, instead of passing `getContext()`, pass the initialised `context`:

   ```
   String[] items = {"item1", "item2"}
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
   chatListView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much! Never would have figured that out. And this is the reason why the adapters are null, not because of fragment initialization?

Comment: Yes, because the adapter is never used in the View that is being returned. The adapter is used on view that is useless (rootView). Returing the rootView will solve the issue

Comment: This hasn't fixed the issue. The adapters are still null when I access them. I'll edit the code in the main post

Comment: You need to pass an array of string as the third parameter to your array adapter for data to be listview to work.

Comment: That's not the required constructor, you can just pass the first two, you don't need data. Even with that, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you check if the value of 'adapter' is null or not?

Comment: And you need to do this: ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter nuffsaidm8.me.assignme.frags.GroupChatFragment.adapter' on a null object reference

Comment: Putting "this" in the constructor doesn't work, its a fragment. Also, putting string in the "<>" is worthless, it doesn't do anything and isn't required because the adapter is declared with ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: that should be context.

Comment: What's the response now?

Comment: Exact same thing. I put the edits in the main post, except putting in values and putting string in the '<>' in the initialization because they don't do anything or aren't needed.

Comment: values are needed. The third parameter is needed because you are not setting any data to the adapter. How will the adapter know what the size of the list is or what data to show?

Comment: Putting new ArrayList<String>() satisfies the compiler, but doesn't change the issue.

Comment: add the third parameter. check the updated code above.

Comment: So, your array works fine and removes the error, but why does it not take an empty string list? Can I still add values to the adapter?

Comment: Yes, you can by adding this adapter.add("item3"); before you set the adapter to list view

Comment: You need to solve a few things by yourself mate. That's all I can do. I have answered your question and I guess the problem you posted is solved.